# that/which with a relative clause

Tags: conjunctions

Good evening, everyone. My question refers to a sentence from my exercise in English:

> Some drivers may notice extra vibration. They *should* bring the car to a dealer for service.

The command of this task sounds in a following way:
Join this pair of sentences into a single sentence. Use that/which and a relative clause, or a present participial phrase. Include modal verbs printed in italics (in this case the word `should`). My doubts concern the doer. It is `some drivers` and, as a result, it is for me hard to join the pair of sentences so as not to change the first sentence. If the subject was `extra vibration`, the task would be easier.

How should I join this pair of sentences into one sentence, avoiding transforming the first one?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Good question. I forgot asking a question :). How should I join this pair of sentences into one sentence, avoiding transformating the first one? Joining by the word "shoulding" would be probably grammatical incorrect. Am i right?

Comment: By any chance do you have an example or a model for this exercise (that shows an original sentence and the modified one)? It is hard to tell what exactly the directions want you to do.

Comment: Yes, I have it. You're right, it can significantly simplify the problem. An example looks like this way: "The company issued a press release last week. This covers vehicles from the 2008-2010 range." -> "The company issued a press release last week, covering vehicles from the 2008-2010 range." And the next one: "The manufacturer stated that there were flaws in the engine valve springs. These could make the vehicle stall." -> "The manufacturer stated that there were flaws in the engine valve springs, which could make the vehicle stall."

Comment: So, if you are still struggling, maybe this could be an answer: "Some drivers may notice extra vibration, in which case they should bring the car to a dealer for service," however this doesn't seem to follow the models exactly.

Comment: Thank you. You gave, I think, a proper enough and inteligent solution, but, as you've already said, it doesn't follow the models. But, as Polish frequently say, it is "close enough". :D Well, the first sentence is the same as it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I posted this in the comments and it seems like it answered OP's question.)

One solution could be:

> Some drivers may notice extra vibration, in which case they should bring the car to a dealer for service.

This works fine, however it doesn't seem to follow the models you provided exactly. It uses a relative clause, yes, but with a prepositional construct, which doesn't appear in either of the models.